# Scraping the distances between two cities using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, excel-2010

I'm trying to code a tool that will let my co-workers quickly calculate the distance between a list of paired cities for a seasonal but pretty vital task for our department.

I currently have it working through the Google Maps Distance API but the constant changes in their policies and payment methods are turning into a real problem, because we only found out the tool had stopped working when we needed to use it.

Which is why I've decided to go around the problem and get rid of the need for the API. This is my first Scraping project, so I'm sure there's better ways of coding this but my solution so far is thus:

```
Sub Scrape2()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim dist As Variant
    Dim URL As String
    Dim i As Integer

    'Creates an Internet Explorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")


    URL = "https://www.entrecidadesdistancia.com.br"

    With IE
        .Visible = False ' "True" makes the object visible
        .navigate URL 'Loads the website

        'Waits until the site's ready
        While IE.Busy
        DoEvents
        Wend

        Do While .Busy
        Loop

        'Selects "origin" field and inserts text
        .Document.getElementById("origem").Value = "Jandira, SP - Brasil"

        'Selects "destination" field and inserts text
        .Document.getElementById("destino").Value = "Cotia, SP - Brasil"

        'Presses the GO button
        For Each Button In .Document.getElementsByTagName("button")
            Button.Click
            Exit For
        Next

        'Waits until the site's ready
        Do While .Busy
        Loop

        Do While .Busy
        Loop

        dist = .Document.getElementById("distanciarota").innerText

        MsgBox (dist)


    End With

    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing


End Sub
```

It opens an Internet Explorer object, inserts the two cities (which I'll replace by information coming from my tool eventually) into the correct fields, hits GO, loads the next page and SHOULD put the number I need in a MessageBox (which I'll replace with a destination cell when I get this working).

My last problem was that half the time, the macro would stop and declare "Run-time error '424': Object required" either on this line:

```
.Document.getElementById("origem").Value = "Jandira, SP - Brasil"
```

Or on this line:

```
dist = .Document.getElementById("distanciarota").innerText
```

I managed to get around that by inserting another wait period before both "problem" lines but that did slow the macro more than I would like.

Still, now it always makes it to the end line but when it does, my MessageBox comes up blank.

This is the info that I need:

```
<strong id="distanciarota">12.4 km</strong>
```

From this website: https://www.entrecidadesdistancia.com.br/calcular-distancia/calcular-distancia.jsp

Any help getting it into a variable or a worksheet cell would be terribly apreciated.

Comment: And you think this is going to be more reliable than using the API?

Comment: I'm testing things. All I need right now is "more stable".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets both distance measurements using their id. I have added a loop with timout to allow for page updating.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, t As Date, ele As Object, test As String
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5               '<5 seconds

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.entrecidadesdistancia.com.br"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            .getElementById("origem").Value = "Jandira, SP - Brasil"
            .getElementById("destino").Value = "Cotia, SP - Brasil"
            .querySelector("[onclick='setRout();']").Click
        End With

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        t = Timer
        Do
            DoEvents
            On Error Resume Next
            Set ele = ie.document.getElementById("distanciarota")
            test = ele.innerText
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
        Loop While test = vbNullString
        If Not ele Is Nothing Then
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
                .Cells(1, 1) = "rodovias " & ele.innerText
                .Cells(2, 1) = "linha reta " & ie.document.getElementById("kmlinhareta").innerText
            End With
        End If
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

You can use querySelector with a CSS id, `#`, selector in the same way e.g.

```
ie.document.querySelector("#distanciarota").innerText
```

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for shortening the code. It's already running faster.

Unfortunately, I'm still getting a error on this line:

.Cells(1, 1) = "rodovias " & .document.getElementById("distanciarota").innerText

It says: Run-time error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: Oops.... ie.document.getElementById("distanciarota").innerText Corrected each instance.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I've started getting a "Run-time error '424': Object required" on the same line. I've also tried using the ie.document.querySelector("#distanciarota").innerText version you showed me. But I get the same 424.

Comment: Works fine here. Perhaps you need a delay before selecting. Try putting Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0,0,5) after  While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

Comment: I have updated with a loop to allow further page loading.

Comment: It's working perfectly, now that I added your loop. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
#If VBA7 Then  
    Public Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr) 'For 64 Bit Systems  
#Else  
    Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds as Long) 'For 32 Bit Systems  
#End If

Sub Scrape2()
Dim IE As Object
Dim dist As Variant



Dim URL As String
Dim i As Integer

'Creates an Internet Explorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")


URL = "https://www.entrecidadesdistancia.com.br"

With IE
    .Visible = False ' "True" makes the object visible
    .navigate URL 'Loads the website

    'Waits until the site's ready
    While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
    Wend

    Do While .Busy
    Loop

'Add additional delay of 500 milliseconds
Sleep 500

    'Selects "origin" field and inserts text
    .Document.getElementById("origem").Value = "Jandira, SP - Brasil"

    'Selects "destination" field and inserts text
    .Document.getElementById("destino").Value = "Cotia, SP - Brasil"

    'Presses the GO button
    For Each Button In .Document.getElementsByTagName("button")
        Button.Click
        Exit For
    Next

    'Waits until the site's ready
    Do While .Busy
    Loop

    Do While .Busy
    Loop

'Add additional delay of 500 milliseconds
Sleep 500

    dist = .Document.getElementById("distanciarota").innerText

    MsgBox (dist)


End With

IE.Quit
Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

'please additional delay after navigate and button click. Ie.busy object active during interacting with server. however, after extract the data from server browser takes few millisecond to render the html content. hence adding the additional delay is best practice to avoid these error.